# How did Yuno become alive again?

Tags: mirai-nikki

As we all know, Yuno died and Yuki became god and became frustrated after that.

[image]

But at the end of that episode, Yuki's diary changes and says that

> Yuno comes to see me

and then someone shouts

> yukki!!

[image]

and then Two started to re-shape World Two.

[image]

My question is that

- How did Yuno become alive again?
- Is this an indication of a second season?

Comment: There is an OVA for the last part of anime

Comment: Check [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12972/6345) if you have completed OVA also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Redial, the Yuno is the Yuno of the third timeline, she inherited the memories of the Yuno from the first timeline. This is explained by Deus that despite the alteration of the third timeline by God Yuki, the persistence of Yuno towards Yuki transcended the timelines.

[image]
Combined with the calling of Murmur and that odd feeling she had (love for Yuki), she arrived and freed Murmur, obtaining first timeline's Yuno's memories from Murmur 1.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Unfortunately i missed the OVA :/ but now i have seen it :)