# Which Yuno ends up with Yuki?

Tags: mirai-nikki

I understand that Yuno and Yukiteru end up together, but I was wondering if it was 2nd-world Yuno (the *yandere* Yuno) or 3rd-world Yuno (the sane Yuno)?

Comment: it is 3rd world Yuno, read [1st paragraph](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12972/6345)

Answer (score 2):

It is the 3rd world Yuno, as I have described [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/12972/6345), in the first paragraph.

> As the 1st world Yuno die stabbing herself. It is 1st world Yuno not the 2nd world Yuno because she was killed by 1st world Yuno(*correct me here if i am wrong*)